# AWS API Gateway, Cognito Identity Pool and REST: can I restrict to specific paths and methods?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, authorization, amazon-cognito, roles

I want to implement a blog API - for fun and learning - which allows a user to manage and write/view their own blog posts.  So far I have an API with paths like

/ - GET all posts,
/blog/{id} - GET a specific post or PUT to update a post
/blog/ - POST for a new blog

Using a cognito user pool, a user can sign up, and login and the API Gateway uses an authorizer to allow or deny access (I'm mucking about with Blazor at the same time - there isn't really an interface yet just a bit of cobbled together C# that uses the identity provide API}.

However, any user can see all posts.  I really want something like this:

/{user}/ - GET all posts by user
/{user}/blog/{id} - GET or PUT specific blog post

and so on.

Behind the API gateway are four really simply lambda functions.  So far, with the user pool authorizer I can see the Authorization header but nothing else (the request context and context have no Identity elements that are not null).

I was wondering whether I could use Identity Pool to do the specific user permissions using IAM Roles, but I cant think of what the roles might look like, or whether this seems possible.  I know there are parameters you can embed in roles - you do that for S3 Roles - why not API paths?

Does this sound plausible or would I need to go down the Lambda function to do authorization?  Anyone any examples?  I googled and look through stack overflow, but couldn't see anything specific around this.

Another problem I guess would be getting a nice ID substitution for user here - I collect email and nickname so far - need a nice username rather than a cognito user id, which looks like they're wouldn't play well with a URL?

Thanks.

Comment: Just adding Identity Pool stuff in C# is proving baffling at the moment.  I think I may have bitten off more than I can chew here...

Answer (score -1):

The answer to my query appears to be in this you tube video, put up by the AWS team late last night (uk time, anyway.)  So far, using C#, I can authenticate myself against the user pool, and get AWS Credentials, but when I attempt to access my API I get "message": "unauthorized", and that's it!

Anyway, onwards and upwards.

[You tube video about fine grained access control using cognito identity pools.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAUmz94O2Qo)